# how to reinstall joomla 1.5 with out loosing data?

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla1.5

I was trying to add custom fields in my joomla 1.5 registration form.I didnt took the backup.Something i messed up.My website is working fine for other modules.But i cant login from backend admin account nor from front end account.it displays this error "The website encountered an error while retrieving http://mywebsite.com/index.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly." how can replace it back to working mode?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

first backup everthing, (also the database).

download a clean install but put it in another folder, then install. now copy paste your newly installed joomla 1.5 folders over the bugged one. if that doesnt work. use the backup to go back and try another way.

Comment: i just want to replace the login component.It shows incorrect password prompt when password is incorrect but throws error when password is correct :(

Comment: then only copy paste the inlog component.

Comment: i hve tried that but its not working.should i replace mod_login?